# ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED in Google Chrome/Firefox kinda works

Tags: google-cloud-platform, dns, google-compute-engine

Got http://norsula.com, and have set external IP(35.228.64.221
) of GC-VM to A NS record.

Listening on 0.0.0.0:80, and everything(?) in firewall allows http connections. Have allow-http in gcp rules

Should work, but doesnt work in Chrome, tells "ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED"

But Firefox and lynx shows page.

Cleaning chromes cache doesnt help, and upon checking on https://downforeveryoneorjustme.com/norsula.com - says it down.

Cant grasp, where and why connection drops, and why it works for lynx.

I want VM serving http for custom domain, cant get it to work for a second week already, probably messed something with NS records, but not sure really.

Edit 1:
[image: Listeners on port 80]
Edit 2: There is another interesint observation. Ping works, while traceroute not. is it relevant?
[image: traceroute norsula.com 80]
[image: ping norsula.com]
python http listener:
[image: python http listener]
this is correct 200 page from norsula.com, firefox shows it too. chrome says err.
[image: this is correct 200 page from norsula.com, firefox shows it too. chrome says err.]

Comment: Your A record resolves correctly. This means you either do not have a process listening on port 80 or you have a firewall rule booking this port. What is listening on port 80? https://www.tecmint.com/find-out-which-process-listening-on-a-particular-port/

Comment: 3 processes show up. 2 of them python (correct), but one is google_gu, which i think translates to google_guest_agent

Comment: fuser shows only python listening on 80

Comment: Show the command used to determine who is listening on port 80 and the results. Is the process listening on 127.0.0.1 or 0.0.0.0? Details are required to help you.

Comment: added relevant information, also observed that ping pings nicely, traceroute drops in the middle, if thats relevant

Comment: I do not see anything "listening" on port 80. You only have internal programs connecting out to other systems. Ping has nothing to do with HTTP (port 80). Ping uses ICMP which is a different layer of the IP stack.

Comment: yes, i realize that ping and trc work differently, just wanted to point it out, if its of any help.

as about not listening, I've added one more screenshot.
there is listener.

actually 2 screenshots, 2nd from lynx

Comment: Please reread the link in my first comment. Delete all the extra stuff in your question that does not apply. Post the output that shows what is listening on port 80. Nothing else matters. If you don't have a process listening on port 80, then you need to figure out what should be listening on port 80 (the HTTP service).

Comment: will delete, but PID 9939 listens on 80. python http listener screenshot

Comment: 1/2) OK, you have a process PID 9939 that is listening but on what address? netstat does not agree with lsof. Listening does not mean that the listening process is behaving correctly when a connect arrives. Sort of like having a doorbell at your front door. Press the button and you can hear it ring inside the house. Someone still has to open the front door and say hello.

Comment: 2/2) In TCP code, you listen on a socket. When a connection attempt arrives, the TCP stack returns, and other code handles the connection (in simple terms). This process is failing as one possibility. There are many more issues that can get in the way.

Comment: Running a [port scan](https://nmap.org/book/man-port-scanning-basics.html) over your vm, port 80 shows being filtered (firewall issue) while 443 shows being closed (no service listening). Are you sure you have the right setup in [Google firewall](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/firewalls#more_rules_default_vpc) over port 80? If the vpc firewall is fine you should check if there is another firewall running in the VM. For HTTPS (443) you should make sure to configure the service. 

`
PORT   STATE    SERVICE
80/tcp filtered http
443/tcp closed https`

Comment: thanks for tip, will look over on fresh head tomorrow morning